# Regex re.findall() search to extract unit beginning with # and postcode

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and trying to extract some building unit that starts with # in a string and some postcode using re.findall() (following explanation obtained here [Extracting phone numbers from a free form text in python by using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527917/extracting-phone-numbers-from-a-free-form-text-in-python-by-using-regex)). I don't know exactly how the structure works and I do not get the result I am looking for. 
Here is my code

```
string='Road #10-13, Tree 26739  #23.04 934047 Holiday'
re.findall(r'[#][0-9(\)][0-9 ,\.\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9 ,\(\)]', string)
```

Basically I would like to obtain something like

```
['#10-13,','#23.04 934047 ']
```

But I only obtain because there is a comma after #10-13:

```
['#23.04 934047 ']
```

What I want to change in my query is saying the string as to end with a number between 0-9 OR ','. Because even if I change the string and add a ',' after #23.04 I would still get the same result.
Could someone also explain to me the meaning of {8,} ?

Comment: You might try [`#\d+[.-]\d+(?: \d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/W8cnbT/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the comma. You problem is that `{8,}` requires a match with 8 or more chars abd `#10-13,` has only 7 total, 5 for that part. Changing it to `{5,}` makes it work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[#][0-9(\)][0-9 ,\.\-\(\)]{5,}[0-9 ,\(\)]', string)
['#10-13, ', '#23.04 934047 ']
```

I would use a simpler approach though, not sure if it matches all your requirements but it certainly works here:

```
>>> re.findall(r'#[-,.\d ()]+', string)
['#10-13, ', '#23.04 934047 ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look-ahead. ie, extract part of the string that starts with an `#` then followed by anything as long as there is a non word character(s) eg space or , that are immediately followed by letters

```
re.findall("#.+?(?=\\W+[A-Z])",string)
['#10-13', '#23.04 934047']
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel the regex could be a lot simpler

```
string='Road #10-13, Tree 26739  #23.04 934047 Holiday'
re.findall(r'#[\d\- \.]+', string)
```

outputs:

```
['#10-13, ', '#23.04 934047 ']
```

Comment: It doesn't? It fails with "bad character range"

Comment: Fair point, that's what I get for using regex testbed and not selecting python. Fixed now.